# How to add item to Model's ICollection List Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-4

I have something like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePost(Post post)
{
    var categoryList = Request["CategoryList"].Split(',');

    //I want to set my Category Name in here 
    foreach (var category in categoryList)
    {
        post.Categories.Add(new Category { Name = category });
    }

    post.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    post.CreatedBy = _userService.GetCurrentUser().Id;

    _postService.CreatePost(post);
    return View();
}
```

I want to set `public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }`this is in my Post Model. It has two properties `Id` and `Name`. I want to set my property in my `CreatePost` method like above. How should I do that?

Comment: just can't see where your problem is?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I got this error Its solving by adding this. Categories = new List<Category>(); but why should create new instance ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is how i solved my problem without create a instance in my `ActionResult` method

I just created instance in Model constructor.

```
  public Post()
        {
            this.Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
        }
```

And this is the right solution for do that.